# how to define one to many in hibernate for this example

Tags: hibernate

I have a table like:

```
PRD_PRODUCT_RECOMMENDATION

        GUID DECIMAL(19,0) NOT NULL,
        PRODUCTGUID   DECIMAL(19,0) NOT NULL,
        RECOMMENDATION   VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT PK_PRD_RECOMMENDATION_L10N_PK1 PRIMARY KEY (GUID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PRD_RECOMMENDATION_L10N_PRODUCT FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTGUID) REFERENCES PRD_PRODUCT (GUID)
```

and another table PRD_PRODUCT:

GUID
  DISCONTINUED
  NEWIMPORT
  EISIDENTIFIER
  STOCKED
  PROTOTYPE

How do I define one to many (one product having many recommendation). There is no 3d table that holds any relation between the above two tables.

Comment: Please consider accepting some answers for your other questions as well to improve the response rate: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
public class Product{
//id and other fields
    List<Product> recommendations;

    @OneToMany()
    @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCTGUID")
    public void setRecommendations(List<Product> recommendations){
        this.recommendations = recommendations;
    }

    public List<Product> getRecommendations(){
        return reommendations;
    }
}


public class ProductRecommendation{
// id and other fields
}
```

I am assuming PRODUCTGUID is the appropriate foreign key to reference for the recommendation.  If not, you may need to introduce another foreign key column.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I m new in hibernate, and defining the relation in hbm file. Will I need two hbm file per class. How do i use list and key used inside to get the collection of recommendation. Can you elaborate this for me in hbm file as well... thanks again

Comment: If you're writing the .hbm.xml files you will need 1 per class.  I prefer annotating my classes, dont know if that is an option for you, but I think it works out a lot cleaner.  On that note, sorry, I dont think im up to the challenge of writing some .hbm.xml files.